# Limiting search scope jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I limit the scope to each group so the sold value reflects the numbers for that group?

jQuery:

```
var sales = (function calculateSales(){
    $( "h1 small" ).each(function() {
        var group = $(this).parent('.group');
        var numItems = group.find('.btn').length;
        var sold = group.find('.btn.hidden').length;
        $(this).text(sold+" of "+numItems+" sold");
    });
    return calculateSales; 
}());
```

HTML:

```
<div class="group">
    <h1>Title <small>Value</small></h1>
    <div>
        <a href="#" class="btn"></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#" class="btn hidden"></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="group">
    <h1>Title <small>Value</small></h1>
    <div>
        <a href="#" class="btn"></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#" class="btn hidden"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var group = $(this).parent('.group');` should be `var group = $(this).closest('.group');`

The [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method searches only the parent node of the searching set(`small` in this case), so it will look only at `h1` which does not satisfies the given selector thus it won't return anything.

Since you want to look at the ancestral tree use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

---

```js
var sales = (function calculateSales() {
  $("h1 small").each(function() {
    var group = $(this).closest('.group');
    var numItems = group.find('.btn').length;
    var sold = group.find('.btn.hidden').length;
    $(this).text(sold + " of " + numItems + " sold");
  });
  return calculateSales;
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="group">
  <h1>Title <small>Value</small></h1>
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="btn"></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="btn hidden"></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="group">
  <h1>Title <small>Value</small></h1>
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="btn"></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="btn hidden"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```